# Issue with Pytest : "import error : Module not found error "

Tags: python, module, pytest

```
repo/
   |--app.py
   |--settings.py
   |--models.py
   |--tests/
     |--uploders
      |--test_app.py
      |--utility.py
```

I have my pytest file in uploaders folder. I have utility.py file from which i want to call the functions in my test file. but i am able to import the utility.py module.I am getting error as

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utility'.
```

I have tried to add **init**.py file in uploaders. But that doesn't work

Comment: Could you please share module usage example. Is it `from utility import ...`? If so you need to use full import relative to repo root. Something like `from tests.uploders.utility import ...`

Comment: I have tried full import too, yet it was failing.

Comment: Please would you share your test python file to understand what is the problem.